# What makes a cricket bowling action illegal?

Tags: rules, cricket

Recently during the IPL-7, during the last match before the qualifiers between MI and RR, Kevon Cooper (RR bowler) was thought to bowl with an illegal bowling action. What are the criteria for bowling a legal delivery?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For the rule about bowling action in cricket visit [this](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws-in-action/law-38-in-action/) link. Also visit [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling_%28cricket%29#The_bowling_action)
[image: The image of bowling action]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/187824) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Source : Quoting **[ESPNCricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/780269.html)**

**What is an illegal bowling action?**

> An illegal bowling action is one in which the bowler's 'elbow extension' exceeds 15 degrees while he is in his delivery stride. The ICC set the 15-degree limit for all bowlers in November 2004.

**What constitutes elbow extension?**

> Elbow extension includes flexion (in this case, the closing of the elbow joint) and extension (the straightening of the elbow joint).

**Does a bent arm automatically signify an illegal action?**

> If the arm is bent at the onset of the delivery stride but remains rigid or does not flex or extend beyond the permissible 15 degrees during the duration of the stride, the action is not illegal. An action is only illegal if the arm flexes or extends beyond the permissible limit while in the delivery stride.

Players IPL reported till date:

1. Sunil Narine
2. Kevon Cooper
3. Marlon Samuels